# Rank of matrices with entries $1/(i+j)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the rank of the $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$ whose coefficients are given by $a_{i,j}=1/(i+j)$?

Comment: The [Cauchy Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix) is a generalization of this, and the [Hilbert Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) is _almost_ your question (it's $a_{ij} = 1/(i+j-1)$.

Comment: a) You should not ask "raw questions" without some "coating" explaining the how and the why of your question b) If your indices begin at 1, the rank is $n$ but, as it is a **very badly conditionned matrix**, if you compute its determinant by a computer, the result will be 0 even for low values of $n$, for example for $m=5$, matlab give 1.5 10^{-14}$..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this matrix $A$ is a Cauchy matrix for $x_i=i$ and $y_j=-j$, i.e., with
$a_{ij}=\frac{1}{x_i-y_j}=\frac{1}{i+j}$ we [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix) that the determinant is given by
$$
\det(A)=\frac{\prod_{i=2}^n\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}(i+j)(-j-i)}{\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^{n}(i+j)}\neq 0.
$$
Hence the matrix has full rank, namely $rank(A)=n$.

Comment: What does it mean that a matrix is full ranked?

Comment: @ItiShree See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)): A matrix is said to have **full rank** if its rank equals the largest possible for a matrix of the same dimensions, which is the lesser of the number of rows and columns

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll see.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_j(x)= \exp(-jx)$ for $x \in (0,\infty).$ Now note that
\begin{align}
\langle f_j, f_k\rangle = \int _{0}^{\infty}f_j(x){f}_k(x) dx = \frac{1}{j+k}
\end{align}
Also note that $f_j$'s are linearly independent function on $(0,\infty).$
Now as the matrix $(a_{j,k})$ being grammian matrix of $n$ independent vector $\{f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n\},$ the matrix matrix $(a_{j,k})$ is invertible and consequently has rank $n.$
(Hint: $\sum\limits_{j,k}a_{j,k}c_jc_k= \|\sum\limits _j c_j f_j\|^2 >0 \,\,$ for all non zero vector  $c=(c_1,...,c_n)$ in $\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: [+1] Very thorough answer.

Answer (score -1):

The matrix represents a positive definite form on a vector space of dim n.;the matrix is non degenerate; is of full rank

Comment: I am sorry : your answer is exact but very allusive : you should say what is the associated quadratic form.